# Change my checkbox into 2 radio buttons (Yes & No) inside my asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code inside my asp.net core mvc to show a checkbox, as follow:-

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SubmissionQuestion.Count(); i++)
     {

       <div class="form-group form-check">
       <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" class="form-check-input" />  <label class="form-check-label">@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question</label>
                        
       </div>
     }
```

but i want to convert this checkbox into 2 radio buttons (Yes and No), so how i can do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use [bootstrap's radios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#radios) to achieve your requirement.

You could use form-check-inline and to let the yes and no radio button into same line and set its value.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SubmissionQuestion.Count(); i++)
     {

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="labeltext">@Model.SubmissionQuestion[i].Question</label>

    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" id="inlineRadio1" value="true">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" asp-for="@Model.SubmissionQuestionSubmission[i].Answer" id="inlineRadio2" value="false">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">No</label>
    </div>
</div>
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]